# Existence of time

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, time

what is time? is time only the change of position? Because we set a standard of 24 hrs and call it a day, but it is actually a change in position of the earth around its axis, similarly 365 days are nothing but again the change in position of the earth around the sun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time is hard to define because it is a fundamental property.

I like to explain *time* as a **measure of change of any kind**. It could be a change in position (motion), yes, but it could also be a deformation, a colour change, a temperature change etc. Any change indicates for us that time passes.

For an objective measure of time we want something that changes *regularly*. Mechanical clocks have been invented for this purpose. You can expect the same amount of time to pass between each pair of ticks. You might hear time explained as: "*Time is that which a clock shows.*" A circular explanation that describes how time is bound on something that seems even and regular. Note that a usable clock could be *anything* regular - a natural clock is for instance the Earths orbit around the Sun.

If nothing changed, then we wouldn't be able to notice the flow of time. Time is a measure of change - that is the best we have. From here on the question might turn philosophical more than technical.